# Lattice Package in R: Is it possible to develop an interactive "scatterplot/network"?

Tags: r, svg, interactive, lattice

I am developing an interactive scatterplot so that when the user rolls over a data point, a label is displayed. However, I would also like to add edges between certain data points.

I am successful at developing the interactive scatterplot using several libraries, including grid, gridSVG, lattice, and adegraphics. Below is a MWE:

```
library(grid)
library(gridSVG)
library(lattice)
library(adegraphics)

x = rnorm(10)
y = rnorm(10)
dat = data.frame(label = letters[1:10], x, y)

customPanel2 <- function(x, y, ...) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(dat)) {
    grid.circle(x[j], y[j], r = unit(.5, "mm"),
                default.unit = "native",
                name = paste("point", j, sep = "."))
  }
}

xyplot(y ~ x, panel = customPanel2, xlab = "x variable", ylab=NULL, scales=list(tck = c(1,0), y=list(at=NULL)))

for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  grid.text(as.character(dat$label)[i], x = 0.1, y = 0.01, just = c("left", "bottom"), name = paste("label", i, sep = "."), gp = gpar(fontface = "bold.italic"))
}

for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  grid.garnish(paste("point", i, sep = "."), onmouseover = paste('highlight("', i, '.1.1")', sep = ""), onmouseout = paste('dim("', i, '.1.1")', sep = ""))
  grid.garnish(paste("label", i, sep = "."), visibility = "hidden")
}

grid.script(filename = "aqm.js", inline = TRUE)
grid.export("interactiveScat.svg")
```

The resulting .svg file accomplishes everything I am aiming for - except that I also wish to add certain non-interactive edges. I tried to do this by incorporating the adeg.panel.edges method from the adegraphics library after defining the edges and the coordinates to be mapped. So, basically my xplot(...) function from before is replaced with:

```
edges = matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2)
coords <- matrix(c(x[1], y[1], x[2], y[2], x[3], y[3], x[4], y[4]), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2)

xyplot(y ~ x, panel = function(customPanel2){adeg.panel.edges(edges, coords, lty = 1:4, cex = 5)}, xlab = "x variable", ylab=NULL, scales=list(tck = c(1,0), y=list(at=NULL)))
```

It seems that this simply erases the interactive scatterplot made from the original xyplot, and simply outputs the static edge and coordinate image.

I tried to follow the example as seen in (http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/adegraphics/html/adeg.panel.nb.html). Specifically, this example:

```
edges <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2)
coords <- matrix(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2)
xyplot(coords[,2] ~ coords[,1],
  panel = function(...){adeg.panel.edges(edges, coords, lty = 1:4, cex = 5)})
```

I am a bit at a loss as to how to troubleshoot this problem, especially as I am mimicking the example code. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to produce is a node-link diagram of a network an alternate solution is to coerce your data into a `network` object and use the `ndtv` package to generate svg/htmlwidget interactive plots for your network.  The `ndtv` package is designed for dynamic networks, but will generate interactive plots for static nets as well.

```
library(ndtv)
data(emon) # load a list of example networks
render.d3movie(emon[[5]])  # render network 5  in the browser
```

Much more detail is in the tutorial http://statnet.csde.washington.edu/workshops/SUNBELT/current/ndtv/ndtv-d3_vignette.html

However, this does not use grid/lattice graphics at all

Comment: Thank you, I am looking over the tutorial right now. May I verify: Could a user constrain data points to certain positions on the x and y axes? What I am trying to do is have a scatterplot with edges in a sense (so each data point has a fixed x and y value, and the graph has a fixed set of edges). The only interaction that I would like is if a user rolls over a data point, information about that data point will be printed.

Comment: you can definitely pass in a set of x and y coordinates (as a 2-column matrix via the `coord` argument) for the vertices/points.  I'm not sure if it is possible to disable the other interactions (zooming, edge hilite)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it! I am keeping the question open as well because I am trying to stick with what I have for the time being. I am particularly curious why my syntax is not successful given the example code. I just edited it to show the exact example code, rather than simply providing a link, so any future responders can see what I am trying to do. Thanks again.

Comment: I know constraints are possible with the WebCola javascript library https://github.com/tgdwyer/WebCola (in particular this example http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/examples/alignment.html), but I have not had the time to build out a full featured htmlwidget using it.  I did start one http://www.buildingwidgets.com/blog/2015/11/19/week-46-colar if you are interested.